# Calculating Total of the row and finding average using MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, average

I have two tables **App** and **Store**

- Grouped : It is the count of application that is grouped ie HasGroup =1
- NonGrouped : It is the count of application that is not grouped ie HasGroup = 0
- Grouped (%) : It is the percentage of application that is grouped ie HasGroup =1
- NonGrouped (%) : It is the percentage of application that is not grouped ie HasGroup = 0
- AverageNonGrouped (%) : It is the average of grouped application ie `(Invidual NonGrouped(%) / total NonGrouped(%))*100`. example for ABC it is `(75/ 165)*100 = 45.45`, similarly for XYZ it is `(50/ 165)*100 = 30.30`. Here  `165` is the sum of `75+50+40`

My query is as given below

```
SELECT 
AppName, 
SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Grouped,
SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS NonGrouped,
ROUND(((SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) / 
    (SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) + 
        SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )))*100), 2) AS GroupedPercentage,
ROUND(((SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) / 
    (SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) + 
        SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )))*100), 2) AS NonGroupedPercentage
FROM
    Apps
    INNER JOIN Store
        ON (Apps.Store = Store.Store) 
        AND AppName !='' GROUP BY AppName
```

I am able to find the columns except AverageNonGrouped (%) since I don't know how to get total NonGrouped(%), Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: How do you calculate "total Grouped(%)" ?

Comment: @DanIonescu that is where I got stucked!!!

Comment: You used "165" in the example, how to you get to 165? ((75/ 165)*100 = 45.45)

Comment: @DanIonescu `165` is the sum of `75+50+40`

Comment: But you also said that the formula is : "(Invidual Grouped(%) / total Grouped(%))*100", and the column 75, 50, 40 represents the "non grouped" in your table, you ment to say  "(Invidual Grouped(%) / total NonGrouped(%))*100" ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @DanIonescu sorry, I have updated my question

Comment: @DanIonescu Any Idea on this....:(

Comment: yep, but it's an ugly query, do you want me to post it? it's not optimal..

Comment: @DanIonescu no issues....

Comment: Does it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's big query, but it does the job (i've tested on a dataset localy)

```
SELECT 
    AppName, 
    SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Grouped,
    SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS NonGrouped,
    ROUND(((SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) / 
    (SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) + 
        SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )))*100), 2) AS GroupedPercentage,
    ROUND(((SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) / 
    (SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) + 
        SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )))*100), 2) AS NonGroupedPercentage,

    ROUND(((SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) / 
    (SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) + 
        SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )))*100), 2) / 

    (SELECT SUM(NonGroupedPercentage)
    FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROUND(((SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) / 
            (SUM( CASE HasGroup  WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) + 
                SUM( CASE HasGroup WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )))*100), 2) AS NonGroupedPercentage
    FROM
        apps
    INNER JOIN store
            ON (apps.Store = store.Store) 
            AND AppName !='' 
    GROUP BY AppName 
    ) AS total) *100  AS AverageNonGroupedPercentage
FROM
    apps
INNER JOIN store
    ON (apps.Store = store.Store) 
    AND AppName !='' 
GROUP BY AppName
```